# YA fantasy novel: boarding school where kids have magical powers

Tags: story-identification

The boy starts out living with his family who all has special powers: grandpa or uncle can channel electricity, blows out lights, three aunts that can do things too. Forced to go to a boarding school, where there are kids that can also do things, like shapeshift, mind control, one can read objects, and the another can channel his African ancestors. He then figures out his power is to step into photos, like his missing father.

Answer (score 11):

This is the [Children of the Red King](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Children_of_the_Red_King) series of books by Jenny Nimmo, also called the "*Charlie Bone*" books.

Per wikipedia;

> Charlie Bone, the protagonist, can travel into photographs and
> pictures. Through his father, he is descended from the Red King and
> through his mother, from Mathonwy, a Welsh magician and friend of the
> Red King. He can use his powers to talk to the people inside them, on
> some occasions he can take items from the paintings. This was first
> discovered in the second book of the series. Main character of the
> series.
>
> Midnight for Charlie Bone is about 11 year old Charlie Bone as he starts to notice strange things happening to him. Charlie gets asked by a book store owner, Julia Ingledew, to find her long lost niece that her brother had traded for a case of some sort. This case was given to Charlie along with this seemingly impossible task of finding the lost girl as well as finding out about his special power. He can read the thoughts of people in photos when the photo was taken. His cruel and uncaring grandmother Bone and her even meaner sisters send him to Bloor's Academy which at first looks like a dreaded thing, but it could lead to the where abouts of the missing girl. With the help of Charlie's friend Benjamin and the loyal dog Runner Bean, as well as some of his family members, Charlie goes on his first adventure to Bloor's Academy with the hopes of not letting Miss Ingledew down.

[image]

Comment: YESSSSSSSSSSSSS. You are AMAZING. I LOVED this series when I was a kid!

Comment: If this is it, you can make it as accepted by clicking the check mark under the arrows

Comment: @USWA - Yes, don't forget to upvote and mark it as "accepted" if the answer was helpful.